# Webpack vendor dependencies and common chunks

Tags: javascript, html, module, webpack

I've recently started to use Webpack to package all my dependencies and I have to say, I'm quite confused as to how to make a working dependency graph between multiple modules. Let's define the problem:

1. Page A uses script SA.
2. SA uses vendor dependencies VA.
3. VA uses polyfills P.
4. Page B uses vendor dependencies VB.
5. VB uses polyfills P.
6. There are common modules in VA and VB.

So the dependency graph looks like so:

```
P <- VA <- SA <- A
   \ VB <- B
```

Since VA and VB have common modules, I would like to extract them to common vendor dependency VC:

```
P <- VC <- VA <- SA <- A
         \ VB <- B
```

So after spending some hours trying to figure how Webpack works, I came up with this configuration:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        P: './P.ts',
        VA: './VA.ts',
        SA: './SA.ts',
        VB: './VB.ts'
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        library: '[name]'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [...]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['SA', 'VA', 'P']
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            chunks: ['VB', 'P'],
            name: 'VB'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            chunks: ['VB', 'VA'],
            name: 'VC'
        })
    ]
};
```

The result? Files for SA, VA, VB, VC and P are created (so I include SA, VA and VC on page A; and VB, VC and P on page B) but Webpack thinks VC is at the top of the dependency graph and places its bootstrap code there. When entering any page, I get an error there:

> TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined

I can't seem to figure out how to configure this thing.

Comment: What if you extracted webpack runtime/manifest to a file of its own? Add `manifest` to one of those declarations. There's also a manifest related plugin you might find handy.